# Prove that the following inequality holds: $P_E(\alpha X+(1+\alpha)X') \le \alpha P_E(X)+(1-\alpha)P_E(X')$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, finance

Prove that the price of the European put option is a convex function of the strike price in one-step binomial model.

In other words, if $P_E(X)$ is the price of the European put option in one-step binomial model, prove that for each $\alpha ∈ (0,1)$ the following inequality holds:

$$P_E(\alpha X+(1-\alpha)X') \le \alpha P_E(X)+(1-\alpha)P_E(X')$$

The right side of the inequality looks like an expectation, and the left side just looks like you can distribute the $P_E$ to make it look like the right side but that doesn't make sense because $P_E$ should depend on $X$.
I don't understand exactly what I am supposed to be doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a payoff of the option with the current price with the payoff of 2 options with up and down prices, X and X'. The latter is higher (for both calls and puts) because your positive payoff kicks in for a wider range (there is more chance that either X or X' will be in the money). If you draw a graph of a simple payoff in both cases it becomes obvious.

Comment: So the payoff with the current prices can either be $0$ or a positive value (call it $A$) while the payoff of 2 options with up and down prices will always be $A$ because we sum the payoffs if the price goes up and down. Basically if price goes up we have $A \le A$ and if price goes down we have $0 \le A$, is this correct thinking?

Comment: @idknuttin no no. The payoff is pv of max(0, K-S) where K is your strike. If both X and X' are either in or out of the money, your payoff is identical to a payoff of a single option, but if it is strike is say greater than X' but less than your original price, the combination of two options starts getting in the money, while your single option is still out